# find a url with a certain word and keep url in an array element 0

Tags: php, regex, arrays, url, preg-match

I have bunch of urls. By using regex pregmatch I want to find the url with the word **artifact**.  Then
I want to keep the url with word **artifact** in an array.

**The language I use is PHP**

These are the URLs

```
https://ct.soa-gw.canadapost.ca/ers/29d0bab4738a301d/10238/0 
https://ct.soa-gw.canadapost.ca/ers/artifact/29d0bab4738a301d/10238/0 
https://ct.soa-gw.canadapost.ca/ers/abc/29d0bab4738a301d/10238/0
```

Can someone guide me.

Thank you very much

Comment: So you are wanting to match any url containing `artifact`?  Or is there anything else to this question?

Comment: @BlackVegitable: Thank you very much for your comments.  "So you are wanting to match any url containing artifact" --> There is always one url with artifact in bunch of URLs.  I want to grab the url with "artifact"   "Which Language" PHP  Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$matches = array();
foreach ($someURLs as $url) {
    if (strstr($url, "artifact") != FALSE) {
        // found URL, store to array
        $matches[] = $url;
        // may or may not need a break here
        // edit: MAY
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, and this is the [second hit of Google...](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

Comment: Given that his latest comment/edit indicated he will always be matching exactly one url, I would include the `break` for sure.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thank you very much for your answer.  Something is wrong in line for($url in $someURLs) line.  This is the message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting ';' in.....   Thank you very much

Comment: @user1427195 of course, because I screwed it up :) Thanks for letting me know that in a civilized way instead of an immediate downvote. See edit.

Comment: Dear H2CO3,  $someURLs is a string with urls and some blank spaces.  Is there way to change $someURL string to an array?  Then I can use $someURL and with your code.  Thank you very much.

Comment: @H2CO3  Great it work!  Thank you very much.  Now I want to clean some stuff in URL. Can you suggest me to way to take off  " 1. artifacthref=  2. Two quotation marks at the begining and end of the url.  The output I got from your code--> artifacthref="https://ct.soa-gw.canadapost.ca/ers/artifact/29d0bab4738a301d/10238/0"

Comment: @userXXX I don't really get what you mean. Please rephrase your question and format your code in the comments.

Comment: @H2CO3  Thanks for the reply.  After I use your code I echo $matches[0] to screen.  This is the output: artifacthref="https://ct.soa-gw.canadapost.ca/ers/artifact/29d0bab4738a301d/10238/0"    Now I want to cleanup the url.  I want to take off artifacthref=  part and two quotation marks at the begining and the end of url.  I want only https://ct.soa-gw.canadapost.ca/ers/artifact/29d0bab4738a301d/10238/0  part.  Thank you very much

Comment: @userXXX this is something you should be able to do yourself. Search php.net for a function that extract a substring from a string.

Comment: Dear H2CO3 Thank you very much for your help.  I select your answer as my accepted answer. Thanks again.